# Extreme slow PC if logged on as domain user remotely

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I'm using windows XP to do the development.

Since I working remotely from home, I found a serous problem, some applications for instance MS excel, even just open up the start menu became to extremely slow .

If I logged into the local pc without domain then the problem fixed, my domain user account has 300 mb local user profile.

Anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: @jms, how do you try a site thats not open to the public yet? >_>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by My documents, as it is been referred to the domain server which is unavailable.